# Pandas pd.read_html error code when table does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I am scraping data from websites, and searching for a table with a certain id. I have something like:

```
table = pd.read_html(page,attrs={'id': 'SpecificID'})[0]
```

The problem is that if the table with that id does not exist, my script stops with the following error message:

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

Is there a way I can catch the error code for pd.read_html? Something like:

```
if pd.read_html(page,attrs={'id': 'SpecificID'})[0]:
    # No error
    table = pd.read_html(page,attrs={'id': 'SpecificID'})[0]
else:
    # Error
    print("Error")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should use a [`try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a try statement:

```
try:
    # No error
    table = pd.read_html(page,attrs={'id': 'SpecificID'})[0]
except:
    # Error
    print("Error")
```